# Elasticsearch.net - Range Query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I'm trying to query an Elasticsearch index from C# via [Elasticsearch.net](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) (not NEST). Specifically, I need to get all documents with a status of "success" that have been created since a specific date. In an attempt to do this, I have:

```
var query = new {
  query = new {
    match = new {
      field="status",
      query="success"
    }
  },

  range = new {
    ?
  }
};
```

I'm not sure what to use for the `range` part. In fact, I'm not even sure if my syntax for the `query` is correct. I don't really understand how the C# syntax maps to the Query DSL in Elasticsearch. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried messaging the github maintainer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
var query = new {
  bool = new {
    must = new {
      match = new {
        field = "status",
        query = "success"
      }
    },
    filter = new {
      range = new {
        createDate = new {
          gt = "2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really understand how the C# syntax maps to the Query DSL in Elasticsearch.

By looking at provided example I assume you want to use `PosData.Serializable(query)`. In this case the query object (no matter what type it is) will be JSON serialized and posted to elasticsearch cluster without any modifications. When you create object using `new {}` C# syntax it is serialized by default to JSON with the same keys as properties of this object. That is, the object

```
new {
    query = new {
        bool = new {
            must = new {
                term = new {
                    status = "success"
                }
            },
            filter = new {
                range = new {
                    date = new { gte = "2018-12-22T00:00:00.000Z" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

will be serialized and passed to elasticsearch as

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "term": {
                  "status": "success"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "range": {
               "date": { "gte": "2018-12-22T00:00:00.000Z" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, by using low level Elasticsearch client you create objects which has almost 1:1 mapping to Query DSL syntax. You can copy examples from elastic.co, replace ":" with " = new", remove quotes from property names and, basically, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

The query would be like:

```
var query = new {
  bool = new {
    must = new {
      match = new {
        field = "status",
        query = "success"
      }
    },
    filter = new {
      range = new {
        createDate = new {
          gte = "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          lt = "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```